# Why is current measured in coulombs per second and not in electron per second?

Tags: electric-current, units, si-units, metrology

If electricity is produced by flow of electron, that is current, then current should be measured in electron per second, why is it measured in coulombs per second?

Comment: Because the International Bureau of Weights and Measures voted to make the coulomb the SI unit of current. You don’t have to use that system of units if you don’t like it. But your courses will probably use it.

Comment: Current is supposed to be charge per second. “An electron” is not a charge. It *has* a charge.

Comment: but it is actually the flow of  electron which produces electricity

Comment: In your wires, yes. In general, no. In particle physics, you can have a beam of protons, or positrons, or muons, or tauons, or uranium nuclei, etc. and *all* of these constitute a *current*. Current is moving *charge*, not moving *electrons*.

Comment: but charge is just the property, how can it flow then and how could it produce electricity

Comment: Because elementary particles with the charge property move. When a proton moves it doesn’t leave its charge behind.

Comment: I got it sir. I've got another doubt how does a moving charge produce current

Comment: Go ahead and ask.

Comment: how does a moving charge produce current, and whenever we define conductor, we would say that it is a substance through which charges can easily pass, but when there is  potential difference across the conductor, it is the electrons that flows through them, then why do we have to say that it is the charge, what is the role of charge in electricity

Comment: *how does a moving charge produce current* This question doesn’t make sense. “Current” *means* “moving charge”. Your question is like asking how moving air produces wind. Wind *is* just moving air.

Comment: As for the other questions, I feel that I already answered them when I explained that other charged particles besides electrons constitute a current when they move.

Comment: Water current is the flow of atoms.  It is more convenient to measure flow in liters per second  than atoms per second.

Comment: so it is measured in coulombs per second for convenience?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If electricity is produced by flow of electron, that is current,

Current and electricity is *not* only electrons flowing.

- Sure, it is **electrons** flowing in metal wires, but
- it is **holes** (positively charged) in semiconductors such as solar panels,
- **protons** in ion beans and fission processes,
- both negatively and positively charged **ions** (not electrons but charged molecules) in electrolytes and other liquid such as in a fuel cell
- etc.

So, in general, current is not about electrons. If it *was* only about electrons, then I agree that a unit like *electrons-per-second* would make sense. But it isn't just about electrons.

Instead, we have to make it something that all the above have in common. What is that? They all have an electric **charge**. And charge is measured in Coulumb-units (just like e.g. mass is measured in kilogram-units). Thus, *Coulomb-per-second* is the unit for current.

Comment: thanks mate, i got it now

Answer (score 0):

The word current is often used by itself instead of the longer, more formal "electric current". Electric current is defined as the rate at which charge flows through a surface. An ampere is the unit used to measure electric current.

Since charge is measured in coulombs and time is measured in seconds, an ampere is the same as a coulomb per second.